# Python socket wait for client connection

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading

Is there a way to stop the while loop until the clients connect to this server?
The server shuld create a new thread for each new client connection, it is possible?

```
import socket
import threading

def clientdialog(myS):
    conn, addr = myS.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))

    while 1:
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                if not data or data == 'q':
                    break
                print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

host = "192.168.1.3"
port = 1998

mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.bind((host,port))

while True:

    mySocket.listen(10)
    #whait until socket don't connect

    try:
        threading._start_new_thread(clientdialog, (mySocket))
    except:
        print("error starting thread")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `socket.listen` function is to be called once, because it sets the size of the connection queue.

Another function called `socket.accept` will block until connections are made. Modify your code like this:

```
mySocket = socket.socket()
mySocket.bind((host,port))
mySocket.listen(10)

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = mySocket.accept() # blocking call
    .... # do something with the connection
```

For more information, visit the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html).

Additionally, you'd want to pass the details of the client socket to the thread. The server socket isn't required. In effect, something like this:

```
def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    .... # do something with client socket
    client_socket.close()

...

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = mySocket.accept()
    T = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
    T.start()
```

You accept the connection in the main loop, then pass the client details to the thread for processing.

Comment: The thread part don't work but the blockant call works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @Racerider Glad I could help. The code I wrote here is a representative example. With a couple of additions it should work. All the best.